# .htaccess redirect does not take place

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I have a dynamic JavaScript link:

```
https://example.com/~scale/playground/[my dynamic value]
```

I produce this value in JavaScript.  Upon clicking this link , it looks for `[my dynamic value]` in my database and redirects to a url for the above value.

**my .htaccess looks like this:**

```
RewriteBase /playground/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

but it shows a 404 error when the link is clicked. Why is my .htaccess not working?

Comment: You're matching only words with your match rule, no dots, slashes or anything else. It would match only a single word.

Comment: May be you forgot to  turn on the  Rewrite engine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this. You can get a idea I hope

```
# RewriteBase equivalent - Production
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost$
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]

# RewriteBase equivalent - Development
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xx\.xx\.xx\.xx$
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/~countryr/]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/-]+)/?$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}page.php?pid=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}blog-detail.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```